# How do I specify the correct return type for mapStateToProps?

Tags: typescript, react-redux

In my `mapStateToProps` below, I'd like to specify an explicit TypeScript return type:

```
interface CounterProps {
    sequence: number;
    count: number;
}

class Counter extends Component<CounterProps> { 

    public static defaultProps = {
        sequence: 0,
        count: 0
    };

    public render() {
        const sequence = this.props.sequence
        const count = this.props.count

        return (
            // Some use of sequence, count ...
        )
    }
}

// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/explicit-function-return-type
const mapStateToProps = (state: CounterState) => ({
    count: state.count,
})
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Counter)
```

However the obvious solution of [using `Partial`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45421935/656912) with

```
const mapStateToProps = (state: CounterState): Partial<CounterProps> => ({
        count: state.count,
    })
```

fails with TS2345 on the invocation of `connect` (`Counter` is not assignable to the expected type).

Alternatively, making the unreturned member optional with

```
interface CounterProps {
    sequence?: number;
    count: number;
}
```

allows

```
const mapStateToProps = (state: CounterState): CounterProps => ({
    count: state.count,
})
```

to work, but results in TS2352 (possibly undefined) for all uses of `sequence` in `render`.

How do I specify the correct return type for `mapStateToProps`, which, by specification, only needs to return a subset of the members of the corresponding type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try out the `Pick<T, K>` [Utility Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#picktk)

Since you're only returning an object with a single property "`count`" from `CounterProps`, you should be able to use `Pick<CounterProps, 'count'>` as the return type for `mapStateToProps`.

`Pick` is also helpful when calling `setState` with a callback when you're mutating the state based on the existing state. For example:

```
interface ComponentState {
  active: true;
  something: number;
  else: string;
}

class MyComponent extends React.Component<{}, ComponentState> {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = { 
      active: false,
      something: 123,
      else: 'hello world',
    };
  }

  toggle(): void {
    this.setState((state: ComponentState): Pick<ComponentState, 'active'> ({
      active: !state.active,
    }));
  }

  render(): React.ReactElement {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: That makes sense, but why won't `Partial` work? And what's the role of `{}` in `Component<{}, ComponentState>` (it breaks my example)?

Comment: `{}` is a [Generic type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html) that describes the `props` of `MyComponent`. It's empty because my example component doesn't have any props.

I can't determine why Partial doesn't work for your use-case, as it works just fine for me on TypeScript 3.5.2. What compiler options are you using?